# Alternating from mobile to destop html

Tags: html, media-queries

So I am working with html/css and I am trying to create a condition with the user agent string.
What we want is to have a condition where it is able to tell if a user is using a mobile or a desktop.
What brought this up was a banner she added to our website, she also created a mobile version of the banner.

I have read online that some people use "@media queries". I watched some videos but I am still struggling since I am new to all this as I have stated before. The banner that is right below is the mobile version.  [image]

[image]

```
        <div class="entry-content">
    <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1535742697651 vc_row-has-fill"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519293449099"><div class="wpb_wrapper"><div class="vc_empty_space"   style="height: 32px"><span class="vc_empty_space_inner"></span></div>
<div  class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center">
    
    <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
        <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img class="lazy lazy-hidden vc_single_image-img " src="//www.pacaire.com/wp-content/plugins/a3-lazy-load/assets/images/lazy_placeholder.gif" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="https://www.pacaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/3Copy-of-Free-Thermostat-Offer-Banner-v2-1.png" width="1700" height="150" alt="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" title="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" /><noscript><img class="vc_single_image-img " src="https://www.pacaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/3Copy-of-Free-Thermostat-Offer-Banner-v2-1.png" width="1700" height="150" alt="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" title="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" /></noscript></div>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use mediaqueries as you mentioned in your question. First you want to create a div that we can show and hide depending on if it is mobile or desktop. I named them 'desktop' and 'mobile'.

```
<div class="desktop"
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div class="vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid vc_custom_1535742697651 vc_row-has-fill"><div class="wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-12"><div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1519293449099"><div class="wpb_wrapper"><div class="vc_empty_space"   style="height: 32px"><span class="vc_empty_space_inner"></span></div>
    <div  class="wpb_single_image wpb_content_element vc_align_center">
</div> <!-- desktop closes -->
        
<div class="mobile">
        <figure class="wpb_wrapper vc_figure">
            <div class="vc_single_image-wrapper   vc_box_border_grey"><img class="lazy lazy-hidden vc_single_image-img " src="//www.pacaire.com/wp-content/plugins/a3-lazy-load/assets/images/lazy_placeholder.gif" data-lazy-type="image" data-src="https://www.pacaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/3Copy-of-Free-Thermostat-Offer-Banner-v2-1.png" width="1700" height="150" alt="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" title="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" /><noscript><img class="vc_single_image-img " src="https://www.pacaire.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/3Copy-of-Free-Thermostat-Offer-Banner-v2-1.png" width="1700" height="150" alt="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" title="3Copy of Free Thermostat Offer Banner v2 (1)" /></noscript></div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div> <!-- mobile closes -->
                
    </body>
```

Next, we edit the css to hide and display the classes depending on the size of the browser. In this case, I decided 600px would be a good size for mobile, but it's hard to get the exact size. Feel free to adjust it to what you want. This code by default will hide mobile and show desktop, when it reaches the media query, it will apply the mobile styles if the screen is less than 600px.

```
.mobile {
  display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .mobile {
     display:block;
    }
  .desktop {
    display:none;
   }
 }
```

Here's a simple jsfiddle example I made. You can see how it shows and hides content based on the size of the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/27xuc6d4/1/

Comment: You guys are amazing! Where would I particularly be placing them? That is also another concern of mine

Comment: and do I even need that other mobile version

Comment: Ideally, you should put the code in a .css file. Normally named style.css. 
If you want to include the style within the HTML code you have (although not recommended)
You can paste the css code with a <style> tag. 
Here's a good reference if this is not clear https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp
However, I'm not sure what you mean by that last part.

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the image when the screen is smaller than a certain px.

```
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
.(imageclassToHide) {
   visibility: hidden;
 }
}
```

for example and vise versa for min width and so on and on.

Comment: It would be "visibility: hidden"